# Delay when deleting directory recursively

Tags: java, windows, groovy, directory

I have the following Groovy test script:

```
def dir = new File("test")
dir.mkdirs()

char[] data = new char[100]
Arrays.fill(data, (char)'q')

for(i in 0..1760){
    def file = new File(dir, "file$i")
    file.createNewFile()

    file.withOutputStream { os ->
        os << data  
    }
}

def delete (File f){
    if(f.isDirectory()){
        for(File afile : f.listFiles()){
            delete(afile);
        }
        f.delete();
    }else{
        f.delete();
    }
}

delete(dir)

dir.mkdirs()

new File(dir, "file").createNewFile() //<-- java.io.IOException: Access is denied
```

Which fails with:

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java_io_File$createNewFile.call(Unknown Source)
    at test.run(test.groovy:29)
```

However, if I amend the test script to look like this:

```
def dir = new File("test")
dir.mkdirs()

char[] data = new char[100]
Arrays.fill(data, (char)'q')

for(i in 0..1760){
    def file = new File(dir, "file$i")
    file.createNewFile()

    file.withOutputStream { os ->
        os << data  
    }
}

def delete (File f){
    if(f.isDirectory()){
        for(File afile : f.listFiles()){
            delete(afile);
        }
        f.delete();
    }else{
        f.delete();
    }
}

delete(dir)

Thread.sleep(1000) // <---- added a 1 second pause after deleting

dir.mkdirs()

new File(dir, "file").createNewFile() // <-- No Exception
```

It will no longer fail. I am running Java 6 on Windows 7 64-bit. Anyone have any idea where the delay comes from or how to account for it?

**Edit:**

Same error happens in Java 6 which is why I tagged it Java (Groovy is just easier to write an example in). Here is the equivalent test which also fails in Java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Test().execute();
    }

    public void execute() throws IOException{
        File dir = new File("test");
        dir.mkdirs();

        char[] data = new char[100];
        Arrays.fill(data, (char)'q');

        for(int x = 0; x < 1760; x++){
            File file = new File(dir, "file" + x);
            file.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = null;
            try{
                fw = new FileWriter(file);
                fw.write(data);
            }finally{
                if(fw != null){
                    fw.close();
                }
            }
        }

        delete(dir);

        dir.mkdirs();

        new File(dir, "file").createNewFile(); //<-- java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    }

    private void delete (File f){
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            for(File afile : f.listFiles()){
                delete(afile);
            }
            f.delete();
        }else{
            f.delete();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Windows blocks files being used. While not an expert in Groovy, I would point to `file << Arrays.fill(new char[100], (char)'a')`. That will need to open a handle. In java, I would said that lots of FileOutputStream objects are being created but none of them closed. The delay allows the GC to dispose the objects, which then unlock the files. There is any method in Groovy to explicitly close the files?

Comment: Changed it to use `withOutputStream` which I know for sure handles opening and closing the appropriate resources and it still fails. I don't think it's a rouge stream being left open.

Comment: I should also note that I tried this with empty files and it does not error. The files in the directory need to contain information for the delay to occur.

Comment: Sorry, I did misread your post. I was looking for an error while *deleting* the files, not when *creating* them afresh. Also I have been googling and I found that `<<` is supposed to close the stream, too. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have done the trick:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Test().execute();
    }

    public void execute() throws IOException{
        File dir = new File("test");
        dir.mkdirs();

        char[] data = new char[100];
        Arrays.fill(data, (char)'q');

        for(int x = 0; x < 1760; x++){
            File file = new File(dir, "file" + x);
            file.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = null;
            try{
                fw = new FileWriter(file);
                fw.write(data);
            }finally{
                if(fw != null){
                    fw.close();
                }
            }
        }

        delete(dir);

        //dir.mkdirs(); <-- commented out
        while(!dir.mkdirs()); //<-- dir.mkdirs() will return false until the directory has been successfully re-created

        new File(dir, "file").createNewFile();
    }

    private void delete (File f){
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            for(File afile : f.listFiles()){
                delete(afile);
            }
            f.delete();
        }else{
            f.delete();
        }
    }

}
```

Still not sure where the delay when deleting the folder comes from exactly but I'm assuming it's just a quirk of the filesystem.